# Fit an abline to data

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm

I have 50 data points of temperature and humidity that I would like to plot on geom_point and add a linear model to my `ggplot`. however, I am unable to do so. I have tried `abline`, `geom_line`, `geom_smooth` and `lm`.

```
temp_humidity_data <- dplyr::select(data, temperature:humidity)

lm(formula = humidity ~ temperature, data = temp_humidity_data)

ggplot(temp_humidity_data) +
geom_point(aes (x = temperature , y = humidity))
geom_smooth()
```

How can I go about adding an `lm` to my `ggplot? any help is appreciated. thank you. And how could i differentiate the temperature and humidity points by colour as well on the plot?

[image]

this is what I have currently ^

Comment: Since we can't see your data or another [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), I don't know why you don't seem to have anything showing up from the `geom_smooth`.

Comment: Missing `+` after `geom_point`?

Comment: @avid_useR good call, this is essentially a typo

Comment: You may also have to specify `geom_smooth(method = "lm")`, as I *think* it might default to `loess`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my missing +. much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment section, you missed a `+` sign after `geom_point`. Besides that, you are also missing a few arguments in `geom_smooth`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Petal.Length , y = Petal.Width)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width), 
              method = "lm", formula = y ~ x)
```

You need to supply "aesthetics" for `x` and `y`, otherwise you would get the following error:

> Error: stat_smooth requires the following missing aesthetics: x, y

`method = "lm"` tells `geom_smooth` that you want to use the linear model method while `formula` specifies the model formula to plot. If we don't specify the `method`, `geom_smooth` defaults to "loess" (as stated by @Lyngbakr) and gives the warning message:

> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'

Since we have to supply the same aesthetics in both `geom_point` and `geom_smooth`, a more convenient way would be to write:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length , y = Petal.Width)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x)
```

**Output:**

[image]

To answer OP's second question of "how could i differentiate the temperature and humidity points by colour as well on the plot?", we can add the `color` and `size` aesthetics to `geom_point` like the following:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length , y = Petal.Width)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Petal.Length, size = Petal.Width)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x)
```

**Output:**

[image]

To change the range of sizes and colors, we use `scale_fill_continuous` (or `scale_color_continuous` for `color`) and `scale_size_continuous`:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length , y = Petal.Width)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = Petal.Length, size = Petal.Width), pch = 21) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x) +
  scale_fill_continuous(low = "red", high = "blue") +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(1, 10))
```

Notice that as you increase the `size` range, some points start to overlap with each other. To make it less confusing, I've used `fill` instead of `color` and added `pch = 21` ("plot character" of a circle) to wrap around each point. This gives a nice border that separates each point.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Hi there, thank you for helping me. this works well. however, when i try to differentiate my temp and humidity data, the plot using colour and size look too similar. Is there any way i can change the colour to something more distinct?

Comment: @MY.BK See my updates. I hope this addresses your question. You can adjust the size and color ranges to better reflect the difference.

Comment: @MY.BK It does if you change `geom_point(aes(color = Petal.Length, ...))` to `geom_point(aes(fill = Petal.Length, ...))`, otherwise, you have to use `scale_color_continuous`. `scale_color_continuous` applies to `color` and `scale_fill_continuous` applies to `fill`

Comment: Ah yes, i overlooked that part. Thank you!

Comment: @MY.BK If you can provide a reproducible example in your question (mainly a sample dataset that people can just copy and run), I will upvote. Right now, people can't just copy your code and reproduce the error you have.